# Ethics Concerning Anwers from Others' Comments

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I have come across many questions (and am guilty myself) where someone (or I) posted an answer that someone had already mentioned in the comments. All the times I have done it I have done my own research to answer the question, but I answer after their comments.

Then I put myself in their shoes. How would I like to have someone else answer the question with the solution I found and commented, and they get the upvotes for it?

What should I do concerning this situation?

Comment: If you really feel bad about it, make your answer community wiki. Then you don't gain rep for it. It'd be polite to acknowledge their comment with a link, too. But generally, it's not really a problem. If they wanted the rep, they should have posted an answer and not a comment.

Comment: As one of those users who rather posts partial hints in comments than a shallow two-line answer: if that's expanded on or mentioned in an answer, it even warrants an upvote.

Comment: This has happened to me many times and frankly I don't care. People who **do** care should really consider if they should be posting comments in the first place.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your post is derived from the work of another, you should be citing that work in your answer.

If your work isn't derived from another user's contribution, but you arrived at the same (or similar) content independently, then just don't worry about it.  This happens quite often and is not a problem at all.  If it really is your original work, then it's entirely fine to post it as such.

Comment: Though if it is mainly those others work, making it community wiki might be appropriate. (See that I said *mainly*, not just *to a significant extent*.)

Comment: @Deduplicator If the majority of the content provided is not your original content, and/or you are expecting others to add their own original contributions to your answer, then yes, CW could be appropriate.  If you are providing an answer with significant original contributions that is simply utilizing the work of another for some piece, then citing it is sufficient.

Comment: Sure. Added a parens making that more obvious.

Answer (score 8):

> Then I put myself in their shoes. How would I like to have someone else answer the question with the solution I found and commented, and they get the upvotes for it?

If they wanted reputation for the solution, they should have put it in an answer instead of a comment. The site is here to provide a repository of *answers* to programming questions, not comments.

If you did the research and answered without seeing someone else's comment, don't worry about it. If their comment led you to post a more complete answer, go ahead and answer anyway, but acknowledge their contribution in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes as a Moderator, I'm asked to close/delete a question because the answer is in the comments.  Instead, I'll simply do the following:

- Post the answer
- Make it Community Wiki
- Link to where it came from as the source

[I think that works better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461237/how-to-use-newaudioclip-outside-of-an-applet/27017944#27017944).

This works in all cases where you feel squeamish about taking someone else's work, and it has the added benefit of not seeming 'self serving'.

Answer (score 3):

One consideration is that it takes longer to post a decently constructed answer than it does to put a one-liner comment - a commenter will typically always win the quick draw race. Also, comment answers are often vague or uncertain (as the commenter knows he/she can delete with impunity later). So if you are still halfway through an answer when a comment answer pops up, don't feel embarrassed to keep going.

When I come across a comment in an answer which either leaves too much to the imagination (if it is too vague), or doesn't fully address all issues the OP is having, I often dive in with an answer, citing the comment and fleshing out where additional value can be added:

*Just to elaborate on @commenter's point, note that foos never intersect with bars because of the baz effect [citation]  ...*

```
code sample
```

***or***

*In addition to @commenter's point about foos, remember to dispose [citation] of your bars once they are done*

```
code sample
```

Comment: That's very much like I how handle it as well. I often use wording like "as already suggested in a comment by @commenter, ...". Most of the time I didn't really need the comment to come up with the solution. But I don't want to give the perception that I might be using content without attribution.

Comment: I guess there's one other angle to this - I've sometimes posted a one liner comment on what superficially looks like a minor typo in the OP's code, expecting the question to be closed, and then suddenly realize there is more to it than meets the eye, so a) delete the comment and b) elaborate in an answer. But a 'comment' then 'answer' by the same answerer can be abused as a way of 'reserving' an answer and dissuading other answers.